One-to-One Messaging with Ably
i know there's already a question with the same title. but i have something more to say
What are my main goals:

I'm trying to let any user from my app to connect to any other user securely, so that no 3rd person can see their messages. just like any normal messaging system (i.e. WhatsApp, Messenger, Discord DM, Instagram DM). Groups won't be available

What I've found so far:

The answer in the above linked question says

The most logical method would be to have a single channel for each
1-to-1 chat (so chat:user1:user2), as this guarantees you have:

A consistent message order between the 2
It's easy to get the history or any one conversation, as it's available via a single
chat request. Generally, the logical division
of chats as channels makes any processing you'd want to do on chats
simple


What issue I've found in the existing answer:

I could be wrong, but i guess the channel name won't be same for both of the users. cuz in
practice, what we'll have to do in the code is chat:<sender_id>:<recipient_id>. and as the
sender_id & recipient_ids are different for each of the users, they won't be landing in
the same channel. hence, they won't be connected with each other.
What I can think of as the possible solution:

maybe we can alphabetically sort the user IDs and then make a string
out of it for the channel name. so both users get the same channel
name. This approach have a security issue. cuz any other user can grab
user_1 & user_2 IDs, alphabetically sort it, and enter their chat
room easily
we can create a hash using user_1 & user_2 IDs (after alphabetical sort) along with a
salt. if we can ensure that our hashing algorithm always generates the same hash string for
a given plain text, we can make sure that both of the users are landing on the same channel
and getting connected. besides, no malicious user will be able to recreate this hash even
if they have the user IDs, as they don't have the salt





Tho this approach creates a secure channel name, but we still don't have any way to get all the channels available for a particular user. and we'll need this to show the list of all the available chat-rooms for that user (we usually see that in the left side of the screen in popular messaging platforms. i.e. WhatsApp, Messenger, Discord, Instagram Web Version). I guess we might need this to implement the notification system as well. Not sure on this. Haven't dived deep about how to implement push notification in the web with ably yet
So my ultimate questions are:

Is my approach good?
If no, what should be the best and secure approach?
If yes, how can I show my users their available chat-rooms?

My tech stacks:

NextJS@14
Ably@2.0.3


Here's directions for a PHP Chat that I compiled for coding awhile back.  Could help for a foundation.

Your approach is good. This would be a recommended way to set-up your channel names in a secure and unique way. The only problem is that you need a way to retrieve your hashed channel names.
Client-side fetching is where you set up an API route in your NextJS app to be called from the client-side to fetch data. You will likely have to set up a caching solution or a database solution to persist your list of previously used / available channels, and the API route will query this.
If you instead do not want to set up a caching / persisted storage solution, you can re-examine a claim made in the post.

maybe we can alphabetically sort the user IDs and then make a string out of it for the channel name. so both users get the same channel name. This approach have a security issue. cuz any other user can grab user_1 & user_2 IDs, alphabetically sort it, and enter their chat room easily

To connect to an Ably channel, you need both the channel name, and an Ably client authorised with a token from your account. Except for basic chat apps built for demo purposes, end-users have no reason to know the name of the Ably channel to which they want to attach. Even if they did know the channel name, from a design perspective the ability to join a channel should be shrouded behind a button clicking 'start conversation' for instance, and never accessible with an input form. As such, there is not anything intrinsically wrong with the chat:user1:user2 design pattern.
For further security, it is possible to assign tokens which restrict the channels available to the Ably Client. If we look at this line for resource wildcards when defining capabilities (i.e. the ability to presence / subscribe / ... on specific channels assigned in tokenParams).

A resource of foo:*:baz will match foo:bar:baz, but not foo:bar:bam:baz.

As such, you could assign in the tokenParams all capabilities to those channels which are either chat:user1:user2 or chat:user2:user1 depending on which is first alphabetically.
capability: {
  'chat:*:<THIS_USER_ID>': ['*'],
  'chat:<THIS_USER_ID>:*': ['*']
}
var tokenParams = { clientId: 'foo', capability: JSON.stringify(capability) };
const tokenRequest = await ably.auth.createTokenRequest(tokenParams);

In this case you remove the hash for the channel names, but retain the utility that users can only attach to channels for which they are one of the users in the direct message.
This doesn't necessarily solve the problem for how to enumerate all of the available chatrooms on the left-hand side, but it makes it easier if a database / cache is not possible.
I am a Developer Success Manager here at Ably. Please feel free contact us for more help or information at https://ably.com/contact
